# Не могу перенести сайт-пример на свой домен(опен сервер)

Tags: opencart, openserver

Я хочу перенести чужой готовый сайт на свой домен для правки.Использую опен сервер, сам сайт на опенкарт. При создании и полном копировании содержимого в новую папку с названием домена получаю такую ошибку. День ищу в интернете, но справиться не могу

> Warning:
>   require_once(C:/OpenServer/domains/webmasterC:\OpenServer\domains\webmaster\system\library\db\mysql.php):
>   failed to open stream: Invalid argument in
>   C:\OpenServer\domains\webmaster\index.php on line 17
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   'C:/OpenServer/domains/webmasterC:\OpenServer\domains\webmaster\system\library\db\mysql.php'
>   (include_path='.;c:/openserver/modules/php/PHP-5.5;c:/openserver/modules/php/PHP-5.5/PEAR/pear')
>   in C:\OpenServer\domains\webmaster\index.php on line 17

Comment: В файлах конфига опенкарта меняйте константы базы данных в соответствии с вашей бд. И, собственно, базы на локалхост перенесите.

Answer (score 0):

В файлах конфига поменяйте пути. config.php в корне сайта и в папке admin.

Вот пример:

```
define('DIR_APPLICATION', 'C:/OpenServer/domains/razves.com/catalog/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', 'C:/OpenServer/domains/razves.com/system/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', 'C:/OpenServer/domains/razves.com/image/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', 'C:/OpenServer/domains/razves.com/catalog/language/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', 'C:/OpenServer/domains/razves.com/catalog/view/theme/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', 'C:/OpenServer/domains/razves.com/system/config/');
define('DIR_CACHE', 'C:/OpenServer/domains/razves.com/system/storage/cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', 'C:/OpenServer/domains/razves.com/system/storage/download/');
define('DIR_LOGS', 'C:/OpenServer/domains/razves.com/system/storage/logs/');
define('DIR_MODIFICATION', 'C:/OpenServer/domains/razves.com/system/storage/modification/');
define('DIR_UPLOAD', 'C:/OpenServer/domains/razves.com/system/storage/upload/');
```

Плюс, не забудьте указать верные данные подключение к БД. Это локалхост, название новой БД, root (обычно) и пустой пароль (обычно).

Подобного плана:

```
define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysqli');
define('DB_HOSTNAME', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'ИМЯ БД');
define('DB_PORT', '3306');
define('DB_PREFIX', 'oc_');
```